# I need javascript for animation to start when div# comes into viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use the draw animation on a one page website, i want the animation to start when i scroll to the div# not on document ready.

```js
var svg = new Walkway({
    selector: "#Capa_1",
    duration: 6000
}).draw();


var svg = new Walkway({
    selector: "#Capa_2",
    duration: 6000
}).draw();
```

```css
   
 path, line, polyline {
     stroke: #fff;
     stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    path {
     fill: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="One" class="left">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1"> </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="Two" class="right">
   <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_2"></svg>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Here is my sample.   https://jsfiddle.net/nsvxq21a/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be enough

https://jsfiddle.net/patrik/89n0h7c3/

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var el = document.getElementById('animation');
var bounds = el.getBoundingClientRect();

function draw() {
  if (window.scrollY + innerHeight >= bounds.top) {
    el.classList.add('animate');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  draw();
});


// Try to draw immediately on refresh
draw();
```